# VB.netSystem.TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc no working on sometime zone(UTC -1:00 Azores)

Tags: vb.net, timezone

I am new to System.TimeZoneInfo function. I found that the System.TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc for UTC -1(Azores) did not work?
[image]

But it work on others?
[image]

Which part going wrong?

Comment: Could it be a daylight saving thing?

Comment: The Azores time zone currently has an offset from UTC of 0, so that's the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran this code:

```vb
Dim azoresTzi = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones().Single(Function(tzi) tzi.DisplayName.Contains("Azores"))

Dim dt1 = #5/19/2020 02:03:10#
Dim dt2 = #11/19/2020 02:03:10#

Dim dt3 = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(dt1, azoresTzi)
Dim dt4 = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(dt2, azoresTzi)

Console.WriteLine(dt3)
Console.WriteLine(dt4)
```

and this was the output:

```
19/05/2020 2:03:10 AM
19/11/2020 1:03:10 AM
```

Notice that the time doesn't change for the date that you're using while there is an hour difference when the date is offset by six months. Your "issue" doesn't seem to be an issue at all but, rather, just that you're using a date that falls within the daylight saving period for that time zone. You're getting the correct result because, during daylight saving, the time in that time zone is the same as UTC.